# sockaddr_in6 not declared?

Tags: c++, winsock, ipv6

I'm trying to port an ipv4 server/client to ipv6, but the compiler says `SOCKADDR_IN6` is not declared in the scope. `SOCKADDR_IN` is declared but not `SOCKADDR_IN6`. `<Winsock2.h>` is included.

Any one have any ideas why it would be undeclared?

Comment: Unguessable without some idea what kind of OS headers you use.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Microsoft's [documentation for `sockaddr_in6`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa915715.aspx) says that it is defined in the `ws2tcpip.h` header, probably you need to include that.

On Linux you'd need different includes, `sys/socket.h` and `netinet/in.h`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Windows. When I said " is included" I meant to say Winsock2.h is included. I put "<" and ">" tags around it so it must have been edited out for somereason

Comment: @Brad: Ah, I should have noticed the `winsock` tag... I edited my answer for Windows and also fixed the formatting of the `<winsock2.h>` in your question.

Comment: thanks that seemed to fix the problem, although now I'm still getting getaddrinfo() isn't declared..

Answer (score 1):

I have currently found `SOCKADDR_IN6` definition in `ws2ipdef.h` header (Visual Studio 2008). However, as said in a comment below, [MS Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740496(v=vs.85).aspx) states that this header should never be used directly (use `Ws2tcpip.h` instead).

Comment: The [MS docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740496(v=vs.85).aspx) explicitly state that ws2tcpip.h should be used and that "the Ws2def.h and Ws2ipdef.h header files should never be used directly."

Comment: I didn't say that ws2ipdef.h should be used (directly), I've just pointed out where I've found SOCKADDR_IN6 definition.

Answer (score 0):

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738664(v=VS.85).aspx):

```
struct in_addr6 {
    u_char    s6_addr[16];             /* IPv6 address */
};

struct sockaddr_in6 {
    short             sin6_family;     /* AF_INET6 */
    u_short           sin6_port;       /* Transport level port number */
    u_long            sin6_flowinfo;   /* IPv6 flow information */
    struct in_addr6   sin6_addr;       /* IPv6 address */
    u_long            sin6_scope_id;   /* set of interfaces for a scope */
   };
```

From your question i see that:

```
SOCKADDR_IN6 != sockaddr_in6
```

Lowercase vs. Uppercase confusion?
You may also not have the latest version of winsock, i'm not sure how far back support for IPV6 was introduced, you may want to check if thats your problem.

Comment: I have the latest version of MinGW which should have the latest version of Winsock. I also tried using sockaddr_in6 as lowercase, but it wasn't declared either. Where would I go to download the latest version?

Comment: I'd say that you're looking for this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924.aspx