# OS X sockaddr_in6 undeclared

Tags: c, macos, ipv6

I'm trying to compile an application on OS X that uses IPv6 sockets but it fails with the error message:

```
error: ‘sockaddr_in6’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I have read a similar question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443836/sockaddr-in6-not-declared), but including sys/types and netinet/in didn't solve the issue. I'm simply compiling with "gcc -o foo foo.c", do I need something like "-lnetinet"? (I tried that but -lnetinet didn't help either)

Simple example:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  sockaddr_in6 addr;
  return 0;
}
```

I have searched for the corresponding files and I've got "/usr/include/netinet/in.h" which includes "netinet6/in6.h" which has the missing "sockaddr_in6"-struct. What am I missing?

Thanks for your help!

Problem solved, I was missing a "struct" tag in front of "sockaddr_in6":

```
struct sockaddr_in6 addr;
```

Comment: What version of OSX?  What version of the compiler?

Comment: OS X is 10.8.2 and GCC 4.2.1.

Comment: And where did GCC come from? And have you tried a more modern compiler (i.e. clang that comes with Xcode 4.6)?

Comment: I tried to compile with cc and it said "error: must use 'struct' tag to refer to type 'sockaddr_in6'". After adding it i could compile with cc and with gcc too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're working in C, so you need to use `struct`:

```
struct sockaddr_in6 addr;
```